# How can I configure IIS (in-domain web server) to use HTTPS if it has no connection to the internet?

Tags: ssl, iis, web-server

I have a web server that runs Windows Server 2016 and has IIS with some ASP.Net applications hosted.

The server is part of a domain, and all machines accessing these applications are also part of the same domain.

The server is behind a firewall, so it can't access the internet.

We are required to disable HTTP communication on the server.

Is it possible to configure the server to use a SSL certificate that all client machines can trust immediately without the browser raising a warning that the certificate is not valid or not trusted?

If yes, then how?

I tried to use (Lets Encrypt) but it requires the server to access the internet, and that's not possible.

I tried Self-Signed-Certificates but the browser warns people that the certificate is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can set up your own CA on a Windows Server and issue your own certificates. All computers in the domain should automatically trust your own CA.
2. Use Lets Encrypt, but use DNS challenges. That means the Web server is not involved but you still need to set up a process to automatically replace the certificates in IIS.

Both approaches require some work.